# how to create a new file in python by passing the arguments as filename

Tags: python-2.7

Here I am passing the value `abc` as an argument for the script. The filename should come as `abc.txt` but coming as `sys.argv[1].txt`.

```
file = open("sys.argv[1].txt","w")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open(sys.argv[1] + ".txt", "w")
```